# doOnTextChanged in infinite looping

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to delete the last character in case it's a number in Android's EditText. However, I am falling into an infinite loop.

The logic I'm implementing is the following: If the user types a number in the first 4 characters, the doOnTextChang event is called and validated if it's a number. After validation, it removes the last character. However, after removing the last character, it understands that it is to be called again, thus being in a loop and freezing the application.

```
var isNum: Boolean
    var charId = ""
    binding.inputId.editTextView.apply {
        doOnTextChanged { _, _, _, _ ->
            isNum = try {
                text.toString().toInt()
                true
            } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                false
            }
            charId = binding.inputId.text.toString()
            if (text?.length!! <= 4 && isNum) {
                if (charId.isNotEmpty()) {
                    binding.inputId.text = charId.substring(0, charId.length - 1)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to do this logic without having to keep changing the keyboard type for the user to type?

Answer (score 0):

=D

Just solve with a simple regex pattern:

```
doOnTextChanged { _, _, _, _ ->
            if (text.isNotEmpty()) {
                if (text.length <= 4) {
                    if (text.substring(text.length - 1, text.length).matches(regex)) {
                        text.delete(text.length - 1, text.length)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).